# How to inject Repository in ordinary classes using hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

MyRepository

```kotlin
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val myDao: IMyDao
){    
   ...
}
```

MyModule

```kotlin
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class MyModule {   

    @Provides
    fun provideMyRepository(MyDao: IMyDao): MyRepository{
        return MyRepository(MyDao)
    }

}
```

Use in Worker

```kotlin
class MyWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val myRepository: MyRepository =
        EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(appContext, MyRepository::class.java)
}
```

start worker in Application class.

but got error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.freedom.android.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl to com.freedom.android.MyRepository`

I read the relevant [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported).But I don't want to use the interface, I just want the class to be provided.

Please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use hilt worker

```
  @HiltWorker class WokerName @AssistedInject constructor(
       @Assisted appContext: Context,
       @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
       myRepository: MyRepository): CoroutineWorker(appContext, params)
```

Go through all the links below you will get all the gradel dependency, how to use them etc..

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#kotlin
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/hilt/work/HiltWorker
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me. I also want to know if this class is not Worker, does it have to define an interface? [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported).

Comment: yes, your right you have to go through that interface way, by the way accept the answer if its helpful :)

Comment: sorry, I'm new. it's helpful.